# Gated Checkin build ignores [SuppressMessage] in source

Tags: visual-studio, fxcop, checkin, static-code-analysis

We want to refuse checkins which break our custom defined static code rules. Therefore we have defined a Gated Checkin build, with "Perform Code Analysis" set to 'AsConfigured'.

When I build the solution locally, using the same configuration and target as defined for the Gated Check in build, there are no errors. But the Gated Checkin build seems to ignore any [SuppressMessage] attributes that we have defined in source, thus reporting errors.

The Gated checkin build does not ignore [SuppressMessage] attributes that are defined in a GlobalSuppressions file.

Any one else have this problem?

Comment: I've seen this before when the `CODE_ANALYSIS` constant was not defined in the projects settings for that configuration. Without this constant defined, all `[SuppressMessage]` attributes are removed from the compiled result.

Comment: It started working after we created a new workspace on the build machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you said you build locally fine, did you build from Visual Studio, or did you build with MSBuild?

TFS Build uses MSBuild to build the projects, and you should be able to see what MSBuild command is run during the build by looking the log from the build report (if you set the verbosity level at least to Normal).

To investigate this issue, I would recommend you use this MSBuild command to build your solution locally (you would need to change the path to the solution on your machine, rather than the path used on the build machine), and it will likely give you the same errors, which indicates a discrepancy between building with MSBuild and building with Visual Studio. Then we can look at the MSBuild command and see why it does not behave the same way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: good idea, I build locally inside Visual Studio. I can try building the solution locally with MSBuild.